# Change in state is not reflecting in component, state should return an array but returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I am trying to do a react app that uses firebase.
After changing state value in reducer and returning it, it is not updating props value accordingly.

Here is my reducer:

```
import {
ADD_NOTE,
ADD_SUBJECT,
ADD_TOPIC,
REMOVE_NOTE,
REMOVE_SUBJECT,
REMOVE_TOPIC,
UPDATE_NOTE,
UPDATE_SUBJECT,
UPDATE_TOPIC,
FETCH_ALL_DATA
} from '../action/action-types'

import { fetchAllSubjects } from '../controller/fetchAllSubjects'

const initialState = []

export const reducer =  async (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_ALL_DATA:
        let data = fetchAllSubjects()
        await data.then(result => {
            state = result
        })
        console.log('state : ', state);
        return state;
    default:
        return state
   }
}
```

Component I am trying to use state in:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchAllData } from '../action/action'

const Subjects = ({data, fetchData}) => {


useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
}, [])

return (
    <>
        {JSON.stringify(data)}
    </>
)
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data : state
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchData: () => {
      dispatch(fetchAllData())
    }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Subjects);
```

My App.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import Subjects from './component/subjects'

// redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './centralState/store'


const App = () => {

return(
   <Provider store={store}>
     <Subjects />
   </Provider>
)

}

export default App;
```

and redux store here :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { reducer } from '../reducer/reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     reducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export default store
```

It's first displaying output as :

{"reducer":{}}

in browser

and after some milliseconds prints state (which is an array of objects of size 2) in the console as I am printing is in reducer

Thank You.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. If Stack Overflow is saying you have too much code, that typically means you should create a [minimal reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of copy/pasting the code from your existing app.